# Targeting dynamically added text value showing empty when passing value on

Tags: jquery

When I select an option from a dropdown, it auto populates a text field based on the choice. When I try to pass that data along however it is always a blank value even though the text field is populated with text.

I tried both of these:

```
jQuery('#test_form #account-test').change('', function(){
    jQuery('#confirmation td.confirm').html($(this).val());
    jQuery('#debit').html($(this).val());
});

jQuery(document).on('change','#test_form #account-test', function(){
    jQuery('#confirmation td.confirm').html($(this).val());
    jQuery('#debit').html($(this).val());
});
```

I am setting the text field value like this:

```
 $('.account-test').val('12345').text('12345');
```

The html for the field is:

```
<input type="text" class="account-test valid" id="account-test" name="account" value="" placeholder="Account" required="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

Comment: can you add the html

Comment: @AkhilAravind I have added the text field html

Comment: id of selectbox and input field is same. so you can't do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the `change` event manually, programmatically changing the `input` element value will not trigger the `event` handler

```
 $('#account-test').val('12345').trigger('change');
```

```js
jQuery(document).on('change', '#account-test', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});

$('#account-test').val('12345').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="account-test" name="account">
```